# Plot of hazard ratio for primary endpoint and continuous covariate

Tags: r, data-visualization, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

I wonder if you could tell me the R code to use to obtain a graph similar to the one below. (from: https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1215740)

[image]

That is, I would like to graph the association between the hazard ratio of the primary endpoint (EVENT) VS a continuous covariate (VALUE).

My cox model is as follows:

```
cox<- coxph(Surv(TIME, EVENT) ~ VALUE, data = EBB)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
require(rms)
dd <- datadist(mydata); options(datadist='dd')
f <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ rcs(glucose, 4), data=mydata)
ggplot(Predict(f))
```

To have more control over the plot use the `contrast` function (full name `contrast.rms`) and plot its results as shown in the help file for `contrast.rms`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Can I just ask you how you interpret the log relative hazard in relation to the hazard ratio? In the graph I don't get the hazard ratio but log relative hazard

Comment: Anti-log of log relative hazard (you can easily plot the anti-log using an argument to `Predict`) is a hazard ratio.   The HR is relative to the reference value for the covariate.  Default in `rms` for a reference value is the median for most purposes.

Comment: This is what I searching for! In the OP's plot the reference point is 100. Can I set the reference point to any values I want with `rms`? And the length of confidence interval should be 0 at the reference point. How can I get the confidence interval like that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to visualize the marginal survival probabilities as predicted by the Cox model using the `contsurvplot` package. You could, for example, plot the survival probability at t as a function of `VALUE` like this:

```
library(contsurvplot)

# refit model with x=TRUE
cox <- coxph(Surv(TIME, EVENT) ~ VALUE, data = EBB)

plot_surv_at_t(time="TIME",
               status="EVENT",
               variable="VALUE",
               data=EBB,
               model=cox,
               t=5) # change to some t of interest
```

To remove the dependency on t you could also use a *survival area plot* or a *survival contour plot*, as described [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37462467/)

Comment: You can also do this with the `rms` package, i.e., `ggplot(Predict(f, time=5))`.

Comment: Yes you are right. In this case `plot_surv_at_t` is equal to your code. However it will produce different estimates if other covariates are included in the cox model. The `rms` package also does not support the other type of plots mentioned.

Comment: The OP's plot focuses on hazard ratio, not survival probabilities. Does this package support HR?

Comment: No it doesn't. If you want a smoothed HR as a function of a continuous variable you can, however, use the `smoothHR` package instead. Personally I prefer the use of survival probabilities though, as they are easier to interpret and have nicer statistical properties.